# rescue that calls a method with a rescue

Tags: ruby, error-handling, rescue

This only prints `rescue 1`, is there a way to print both `rescue 1` and `rescue 2`?

```
def mimiti
  raise 'hi there!'
rescue
  puts 'rescue 1'
end

begin
  mimiti
rescue
  puts 'rescue 2'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can re-raise an exception after catching and handling it:

```
def mimiti
  raise 'hi there!'
rescue StandardError => e
  puts 'rescue 1'
  raise e
end
```